# Consulta con Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Agradezco sus respuestas y recomendaciones sobre esta pregunta estoy empezando a usar Scopes en Laravel tengo una tabla images y una tabla users en mi base de datos quiero hacer una consulta de este tipo:
Tráeme todas las imágenes cuyos autores tengan el nombre de Darinel.
He conseguido hacer la consulta en sql pero quiero saber como se haría con Eloquent

```
SELECT * FROM images where user_id
  IN(SELECT id FROM users where name LIKE "%darinel%");
```

Añado la estructura de mi base de datos por si las dudas:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De ante mano muchas gracias por sus respuestas:)

Comment: En estos casos siempre se agradece que muestres lo que has intentado, de otro modo la pregunta puede quedar cerrada

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dices que estás empezando a trabajar con scopes, pero tu pregunta es acerca de la equivalencia entre cierta sentencia SQL y lo propio con Eloquent.

Si entiendo bien, y necesitas formular esa consulta o filtro con un scope, primero debieras cerciorarte de haber declarado que una imagen pertenece a un usuario.

```
<?php

namespace App\Models; // en versiones anteriores de Laravel es sólo "App"

use App\Models\User; // en versiones anteriores, App\User
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;

class Image extends Model

   public function author() {
      return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
   }
```

Si estamos ok con eso, declaras un método para el scope. Por ejemplo si luego querrás usarlo como `authorNameLike` entonces el método debe llamarse `scopeAuthorNameLike`

```
   public function scopeAuthorNameLike(Builder $query, string $search='') {
      return $query
              ->whereHas('author', function(Builder $subQuery) use ($search) {
                  $subQuery->where('nombre','LIKE', $search)
              });
   }
```

Y luego podrías usar ese método como

```
     $imagenesDeDarinel = Image::authorNameLike('%Darinel%')->get();
```

Procura ajustar el namespace de mi ejemplo a los que usa tu proyecto, mira que no necesariamente será `App\Models`. También fíjate que la relación se llama `author`. Da igual si le quieres llamar `user` pero debes usar el mismo nombre en la relación y dentro del scope como primer parámetro de `whereHas`.

Nótese también que aunque un scope recibe y retorna un Builder, la subquery que va dentro del whereHas no retorna. Eso es a propósito.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías realizar la siguiente consulta:

```
Imagenes::whereHas('user', function($query){
      $query->where('nombre', 'like', '%daniel%');
})->get();
```

EDITO:
Eloquent te provee de un metodo **toSql()** así podrás hacer un debug de lo que solicitas a tu db.

```
Imagenes::whereHas('user', function($query){
      $query->where('nombre', 'like', '%daniel%');
})->toSql();
```

La consulta es mas o menos así:

```
 "select * from `imagenes` where exists (select * from `users` where `imagenes`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` and `nombre` like ? and `users`.`deleted_at` is null) and `imagenes`.`deleted_at` is null"
```

Acá la [documentacion](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence)

Comment: Habría que aclararle que esa consulta depende de qué el OP tengas las relaciones de Eloquent declaradas

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta tan pronta me ha servido para aclarar algunas dudas:)

Answer (score 0):

Gracias por sus respuestas ambas me han sido de ayuda, comparto como quedo resuelto mi problema por si alguien más tiene problemas con esto.
Mi modelo quedo de la siguiente manera:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;

class Image extends Model
{

  
    public function user(){

        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    // Scope
    public function scopeDescription($query, $description){
        if($description)
            return $query->where('description', 'LIKE', "%$description%");    
    }

    public function scopeName($query, $name) {
        return $query->whereHas('user', function(Builder $subQuery) use ($name) {
                    $subQuery->where('name','LIKE', "%$name%");
                });
     }

}
```

El código de mi controlador donde llamo el Scope:

```
public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $description    =   $request->description;
        $name           =   $request->name;

        $images = Image::orderByDesc('created_at')
                ->description($description)
                ->name($name)
                ->paginate(3);

        return view('home', compact('images'));
    }
```

Formulario donde mando los datos que deseo buscar por GET:

```
<form action="{{ route('home') }}" method="GET" class="d-flex">
   <input class="form-control me-2" name="name" type="search">
   <input class="form-control me-2" name="description" type="search">
   <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Buscar</button>
</form>
```